# Error: invalid conference type value while creating event with google meet link

Tags: javascript, php, google-calendar-api

I configured calendar API in my web application and it is working fine. I wanted to add google meet link while creating event. After reading docs I added following code:

```
'conferenceDataVersion' => 1,
            'conferenceData' => [
                'createRequest' => [
                  'conferenceSolutionKey' => [
                    'type' => 'eventNamedHangout'
                  ],
                  'requestId' => 'sample232212'
                ]
            ],
```

I am getting error:

```
{
"error": {
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"reason": "invalid",
"message": "Invalid conference type value."
}
],
"code": 400,
"message": "Invalid conference type value."
}
}
```

I also try with "eventHangout" and  "hangoutsMeet" as per the docs but no luck. I am using google service account. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

The object shouldnt contain arrays

```
"conferenceData": {
      "createRequest": {
        "conferenceSolutionKey": { "type": "eventNamedHangout" },
        "requestId": "randomvalue"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue:

You are adding `conferenceDataVersion` to the request body, when it's actually a request parameter.

#### Solution:

Remove `conferenceDataVersion` from the request body:

```
'conferenceData' => [
    'createRequest' => [
      'conferenceSolutionKey' => [
        'type' => 'hangoutsMeet'
      ],
      'requestId' => 'sample232212'
    ]
],
```

And add it as an additional parameter when making the request:

```
$optParams = ['conferenceDataVersion' => 1];
$service->events->insert($calendarId, $postBody, $optParams);
```

#### Reference:

- [Events: insert > Parameters](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#parameters)
- [PHP library: Events.insert](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/calendar/v3/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Calendar_Events_Resource.html#_insert)

Comment: I try with that but no luck

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using for this request? Also, are you sure the `requestId` you are providing is unique?

Comment: @MuhammadHarisRiaz Can you provide the code you are using for this request? Also, are you sure the `requestId` you are providing is unique?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the similar situation, so I'm sharing my solution here.

As of now, it seems that using GoogleAuth with a Service Account does not allow the creation of Google Meet events via the Google Calendar API, even with domain delegation.

This is my personal interpretation, but it appears that the authentication logic used by Google Service Accounts and Google Workspace Users differs, even when using domain delegation. Therefore, the conclusion is that you can only create Google Meet events via the Google Calendar API by using impersonating GoogleAuth.

This feature also has [a serious problem](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/916). Then, you have to use SecretManager for service-account-key.json.

Below is the code from a Nestjs application that I created.

```
@Injectable()
export class GoogleCalendarService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(GoogleCalendarService.name);
  private readonly calendar: calendar_v3.Calendar;

  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {
    const googleAuth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
      keyFile:
        process.env.STAGE === 'dev'
          ? this.configService.get('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
          : undefined,
      credentials:
        process.env.STAGE === 'dev'
          ? undefined
          : JSON.parse(this.configService.get('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY') as string),
      scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'],
      clientOptions: {
        subject: this.configService.get('SOME_EMAIL_ADDRESS'),
      },
    });
    this.calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth: googleAuth });
  }
}
```

I hope this answer will help you.